# Регулярка для serialize

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Приветствую. помогите пожалуйста с регуляркой. 
Есть строка:

```
a:2:{s:2:"en";s:6:"record";s:2:"ru";s:6:"Запись";}
```

Вот регулярка

```
s:2:\"en\";s:\d+:\"+?.*(Запись).*\"+?;+?
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы регулярное выражение было ограничено это подстрокой s:2:"en";s:6:"record"; ? То есть, искало "Запись" в первых кавычках после "en".

.*(Запись).* - это нужно, поскольку будут встречаться не одиночные слова, а предложения с разнообразными символами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение

> .*

означает любые символы, в том числе и кавычки, нужно заменить это на

> [^\"]*

все, кроме двойных кавычек, получаем

```
s:2:\"en\";s:\d+:\"+?[^\"]*(Запись)[^\"]*\"+?;+?
```